# Python/pandas: reshaping of data based on date intervals

Tags: python, date, pandas, intervals, reshape

I have a database of prices valid for some date intervals, in some specific clusters denoted by `A, B, C,...`
Several prices can be available for the same day in a specific cluster.
Example:

```
Cluster  DateStart DateEnd  Price 
A        01/01     31/01    50
A        02/01     04/01    70
B        08/07     26/08    90
B        08/07     12/08    80
```

Here, in cluster A, both prices 50 and 70 are available for the period `[02/01-04/01]`.

I want to reshape these data (in a new dataframe) with highest price for each day given in the date intervals. This would result for the example above in:

```
Cluster  Date   Price
A        01/01  50
A        02/01  70 
A        03/01  70
A        04/01  70
A        05/01  50
.        .      .
.        .      .
B        08/07  90
B        09/07  90
.        .      .
.        .      .
```

I am transforming the date intervals to a list of days using `date_range(DateStart,DateEnd)`. 
I append two blocs of dates using something like `dates.append( date_range(df.DateStart.iloc[i],df.DateEnd.iloc[i])  )`, looping on both clusters and date intervals, but the appending results in a non-flat list. How to do it properly?

Moreover, is there a way of doing this without using a double `for` loop? I am pretty convinced that yes, but don't know how.

Comment: How is the `50` price available for the period `[02/01-04/01]`, since there appears to be no overlap between the two time periods in cluster A?

Comment: Is my solution helpful?